# Determine $\inf\{x \mid x \in [0, \infty) \setminus \mathbb{Q} \}$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine $\inf\{x \mid x \in [0, \infty) \setminus \mathbb{Q} \}$.

I was convinced this would be $0$, but $0$ isn't irrational number. This set is the irrationals right? In order to find the infimum I need to get that if $\inf\{x \mid x \in [0, \infty) \setminus \mathbb{Q} \} = a$, then for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $x_\varepsilon$ such that $x_\varepsilon < a + \epsilon$. So if I add any positive real number to $a$ then it isn't a lower bound anymore. How should I approach this?

Comment: Infima and suprema do not respect (ir)rationality because neither set is complete in the real line (with the usual notion of completeness). The answer is indeed $0$. This can be seen very easily by taking the sequence $\frac{\pi}{n}$.

Comment: An infimum of a set may not necessarily belong to the set. The infimum of $(3,4)$ is $3$. Presently, consider the sequence $\{1/(\sqrt2)^{2n-1}\},n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Let me see if I understood this correctly. The set $\{\frac{\pi}{x} \mid x \in \mathbb{R_{+}}\}$ characterizes the pos irrationals? This means I can consider $\inf \{\frac{\pi}{x} \mid x \in \mathbb{R_{+}}\}$ instead of the original problem? Now the claim is that $\inf \{\frac{\pi}{x} \mid x \in \mathbb{R_{+}}\} = 0$ so I want to show that $\exists x \in \mathbb{R_{+}}$ such that $\frac{\pi}{x} < 0 + \varepsilon$? From here I get that this is true whenever $x > \frac{\pi}{\varepsilon}$. And this means that there is an $x$ so that all other lower bounds of the irrationals are greater than zero?

Answer (score 3):

The infimum of a set is just its greatest lower bound.   $0$ is clearly a lower bound of the set.  If you had any other lower bound, you can show it must be negative (Because any positive number isn't a lower bound, you can find a smaller positive irrational).   Thus 0 is the infimum.

We use inf and sup specifically in place of maximum and minimum to allow for the cases where there isn't a smallest/biggest point in the set but it is still bounded

Answer (score 2):

Let us mark the set of positive irrationals $A:=\{x|x \in [0,\infty) \setminus \Bbb Q \}$. Then $ \forall x \in A: 0 \leq x$, thus $0$ is a lower bound of $A$. Let now an $\epsilon >0$; from density of the irrationals in $\Bbb R$ there exists an irrational $r \in (0,\epsilon)$. But $r$ is a positive irrational, so $r \in A$. By the characterization of infimum we have prooved that $\inf A=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** For all $n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}$ we have
$$
1-\sqrt[\,n\,]{2}\in \{x \, | \, x\in [0,\infty)\backslash\mathbb{Q}\}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}( 1- \sqrt[\, n \, ]{2})=0
$$

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks.